# Exception in PredictionEngineBase when using Time Series model with PredictionEnginePool (ML.NET)

Tags: c#, machine-learning, ml.net

I've created a Time Series model using the method described [here](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/tree/master/samples/csharp/end-to-end-apps/Forecasting-Sales) resulting in this code:

```
var data = items.ToArray();
var trainData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(data);

var estimator = mlContext.Forecasting.ForecastBySsa(
    nameof(FooPrediction.BarPrediction),
    nameof(FooInput.Bar),
    12,
    data.Length,
    data.Length,
    2,
    confidenceLowerBoundColumn: nameof(FooPrediction.ConfidenceLowerBound),
    confidenceUpperBoundColumn: nameof(FooPrediction.ConfidenceUpperBound));

var transformer = estimator.Fit(trainData);
using var engine = transformer.CreateTimeSeriesEngine<FooInput, FooPrediction>(mlContext);
engine.CheckPoint(mlContext, "model.zip");
```

where `items` is `IEnumerable<FooInput>`. These are my model classes:

```
public class FooPrediction
{
    public float[] BarPrediction { get; set; }

    public float[] ConfidenceLowerBound { get; set; }

    public float[] ConfidenceUpperBound { get; set; }
}

public class FooInput
{
    public float Bar { get; set; }

    public float Baz { get; set; }
}
```

In my `Startup`, I add a `PredictionEnginePool` thus:

```
services.AddPredictionEnginePool<FooInput, FooPrediction>().FromFile(String.Empty, "model.zip", true);
```

In my middleware service, I inject the `PredictionEnginePool` and then call:

```
var prediction = items.Select(i => predictionEnginePool.Predict(i));
```

where `items` is `IEnumerable<FooInput>`.

This results in an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` being thrown in `PredictionEngineBase.TransformerChecker`:

> Must be a row to row mapper (Parameter 'transformer')

Debugging into the code, I can see there is a check for `IsRowToRowMapper` on the `ITransformer` object being true. However, when the model is created, an `SsaForecastingTransformer` is created which has this property set to false.

Am I doing something wrong, or does `PredictionEnginePool` not support Time Series models?

I've also tried this with `AddPredictionEnginePool<IEnumerable<FooInput>, FooPrediction>` and then calling `predictionEnginePool.Predict(items)`, but this also results in the same exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code has been added after my time, so I don't have firsthand knowledge.

However, as far as I know ML.NET, the answer is yes: most likely, `PredictionEnginePool` does not support the time series prediction.

The reason is, the time-series prediction engine is actually a 'state machine'. You need to feed *all* the data, *in the correct sequence*, to *one* prediction engine, so that it correctly reacts to this 'time series'.

Prediction engine pool is solving a completely different scenario: if you have truly stateless models, you may instantiate a handful of interchangeable instances (a pool) of prediction engines, and the predictions will be handled with whatever engine is currently free.

These 'stateless' models are represented by a 'row to row mapper' concept in the codebase. Basically, the prediction of this model is determined exclusively, and solely, on *one row of data*.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. A [similar reply](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/issues/739#issuecomment-552004422) was given in the GitHub issue I raised for this, by a current team member (I think). All makes sense, and I'll go ahead and use `TimeSeriesPredictionEngine` for Time Series models.